# Fermentation time

Tags: fermentation, all-grain, dry-hop

I am looking for some advice.

I successfully completed a first all grain batch on the brewzilla (OG 1.048). Airlock activity ~every min at day 14 (yeast S-04 @ 18dc).
Dry hopped loose (~80g total) on day 10.

Should I just let go until no activity? How long is too long?
What about the hops, how long can you dry hop for?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let it go. Hops contain enzymes so you are likely seeing renewed fermentation which could continue in the bottles or keg if you package it too quickly. Concerns regarding prolonged contact with dry hops are largely overblown. In my experience you are unlikely to experience any detrimental effects for several more weeks and it will not take that long for fermentation to cease unless there might be some unlikely contamination by wild yeast. Let it ride. When in doubt I find that patience is always the best option.

Answer (score 2):

The main indication would be to measure the final gravity of the wort, don't look at the activity in the airlock. However, if you kept it in a room without too much temperature variation at ambient temperature, it should be finished.

W.r.t. to the dry hop, my experience is that it is more dependent upon the variety of the hops if you get off-flavors from dry hopping. I successfully dry hopped for a couple weeks without grassy aftertastes, but I also dry hopped with bittering hops (just experimenting) which gave an extra bitter edge to the beer.